# Jquery + Ajax Can't receive html button value

Tags: jquery, ajax, button

here is my jquery function:

```
function showNewWindow(){
    $('#result').slideDown('slow');
    $("#result").html('<div id=resim><center><img src="loading.gif"></center></div>');
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'windowLoader.php',
        data:$('#windowName').serialize(),
        success:function(response){
            $("#result").html(response)
        }
    })
}
```

What i want to do:
I have a menu, which include lot's of pages in it. I want it to load the page the user selected without refreshes in browser.

My form has an id as you can understand. 
if i store the get information in a hidden html input, it parses the first input and doesn't see others. (every page has different names)
So i thought that, if i store the data in buttons, the problem will be solved. But this time; no GET sent to windowLoader.php.

I don't want to write different functions in jquery or seperate if's in php because it will be a silly thing to do.

Could anyone please help me about that trouble?

Comment: Can you show us the HTML as well?

Comment: what is this id '#windowName', And also can you put comments on the code so that will be easy to understand it and the other thing is, I am confused on why you using a form with a menu.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using $.get(...) instead of $.ajax(...), as this method is meant to be at a very low level. try this:

```
function showNewWindow(){
$('#result').slideDown('slow');
$("#result").html('<div id=resim><center><img src="loading.gif"></center></div>');
var myData = $('#windowName').serialize();
$.get("windowLoader.php", 
    myData, 
    function(data){
        $('#result').html(data);
    }, 
    "html");
}
```

Comment: @user341652:
thanks for your valuable reply. But no change. Here is what i mean <form id="windowName"><input type="hidden" name="pageName" value="main" /></form><form id="windowName"><input type="hidden" name="pageName" value="bookShelf" /></form>. it see just the firs form. So i have to send theese values in the button which include onClick event in it.

Comment: You should be using the JQuery form plug-in then if you are trying to submit the entire form. Its fairly light-weight, and it will accomplish exactly what you are looking to do. The $.serialize() method is meant for a single value, not the entire form.